# select the nearest date in mysql using codeigniter from two different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

These are my two different tables ..
1) seminar

[image: seminar table]

2) workshop

[image: workshop table]

Need to show the nearest event by using the column posted_datetime(timestamp)..
how to get only one record which is nearest to current date using codeigiter ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a union with a return limit of 1.

```
select 1, * from seminar
UNION
select 2, * from workshop
ORDER BY posted_datetime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I put the leading 1 and 2 in the first column so you can tell if the returned record is a workshop (1) or seminar (2). This whole thing assumes all the fields names are the same in both tables and the bigger assumption, that my untested sql will actually work. =)

Answer (score 0):

this query will return you upcoming nearest seminar

select * from seminar where posted_datetime < now() order by posted_datetime desc limit 1

In CI

```
$this->db->where('posted_datetime < now()');
$this->db->order_by('posted_datetime','desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
$this->db->get('seminar');
```